# How to inject map and filter based on map content in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am running JanusGraph server and connected to it from gremlin console.

As can be seen, I have two vertices, with id property set to 1 and 2

```
gremlin> g.addV('user').property('id', 1)
==>v[4224]
gremlin> g.addV('user').property('id', 2)
==>v[4192]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>{id=[2]}
==>{id=[1]}
```

Next, I injected a map arraylist with different properties. I am trying to loop over this map and filter the vertices, but I couldn't figure out why the query isn't working. Can someone please help me figure out right query?

I tried using terminal step next() after select("id"), but that failed too.

```
gremlin> g.inject([["id": 1], ["id": 2, "something":"anything"]]).unfold().as("m").V().has("user", "id", select("m").select("id"))
Value [[SelectOneStep(last,m), SelectOneStep(last,id)]] is not an instance of the expected data type for property key [id] and cannot be converted. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, found: class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

I can't use `g.V().has(label, key, within(...))`, as I need to use same map in multiple places and repeat steps for each row.

Comment: `has(..., Traversal)` is quite misunderstood. It is meant to filter traversers that do not yield a result through the traversal off the *property value*. It's not saying inject the result of `select("m").select("id")` into the `has()` and use that value to determine if the filter is valid. what is the final goal of your traversal in using that `Map`?

Comment: @stephenmallette
Final goal is to be able to manipulate few vertices.
Lets say input is `[["id": 1, "something":"anything1"], ["id": 2, "something":"anything2"]]`

Then I would like to be able to do to below in one go
-> find user vertex with id "1", then go to company (college) user works for and add property on that vertex anything1.
-> find user vertex with id "2", then go to company (college) user works for and add property on that vertex anything2. @stephenmallette

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably take a different approach to my traversal and avoid `inject()` in this case. With `inject()` you will have to unfold your list of `Map` objects and then do a vertex lookup for each which is probably expensive on all graph systems if your list is on the long side. I'd also wonder if you could write the traversal in such a way that graph systems will be able to optimize your vertex lookups with an index.

Given all that and your end goal of the traversal to update the properties of the found vertices I think I'd take this approach:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('user').property('id', 1)
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.addV('user').property('id', 2)
==>v[2]
gremlin> m = [["id": 1], ["id": 2, "something":"anything"]]
==>[id:1]
==>[id:2,something:anything]
gremlin> ids = m.collect{it.id}
==>1
==>2
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('m',m).
......1>   V().has('user','id',within(ids)).as('v').
......2>   sideEffect(select('m').unfold().
......3>              filter(select('id').as('ii').
......4>                     where('ii',eq('v')).
......5>                       by().
......6>                       by('id')).
......7>              unfold().as('kv').
......8>              select('v').
......9>              property(select('kv').by(keys),select('kv').by(values)))
==>v[0]
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().elementMap()
==>[id:0,label:user,id:1]
==>[id:2,label:user,id:2,something:anything]
```

Here, we find all the vertices with `within()` as a single lookup and then `filter()` the list of data by the current vertex "id" property to then update the properties.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I do not expect size of the map to be large, maybe ~10 rows. This solution solves my original problem, but in my case, there could be duplicate entries.
`[["id": 1], ["id": 2, "something":"anything"], ["id":1, "something1": "anything2]]`
Basically, each map contains series of instructions that needs to be applied, not just on that vertex, but its neighbors. This makes it hard for me preprocess and combine entries or to use within. Neverthless, your solution solves my original problem

Comment: Then I suppose you would just use `inject()` as you were doing, that way you get one traverser per `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query, it should work:

```
g.inject([["id": 1], ["id": 2, "something":"anything"]]).
  unfold().as("m").
  V().
  hasLabel("user").
  has("id", select("m").select("id")).
  dedup()
```

Your query failed because `has(label, propertyKey, traversal)` is not valid syntax. You can either use `has(label, propertyKey, propertyValue)` or `has(label, propertyKey, predicate)`

Comment: This solution didn't work :(

`gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>{id=[3]}
==>{id=[4]}
==>{id=[2]}
==>{id=[1]}`

This gives me all 4 vertices instead of just two

`gremlin>  g.inject([["id": 1], ["id": 2, "something":"anything"]]).unfold().as("m").V().hasLabel("user").has("id", select("m").select("id")).dedup().valueMap()
==>{id=[3]}
==>{id=[4]}
==>{id=[2]}
==>{id=[1]}`